# Is it possible to set up a gcc cross compiler on Linux to compile 64 bit targets on a 32 bit architecture?

Tags: linux, 32bit-64bit, cross-compiling

I know you can compile to a 32 bit target on 64 bit Linux by using the -m32 flag, but is it also possible to compile to 64 bit on a 32 bit machine by using the -m64 flag?

Or alternatively, do you need to set up a cross gcc tool chain that supports 64 bit targets and is this possible on a 32 bit machine?

Regards,
Johan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As MarkR said, it will be a lot easier to run a 64-bit VM and build from there.  Otherwise, yes, you will need to build a gcc cross toolchain.

Good ressources for building a gcc cross toolchain :

- [Building and Testing gcc/glibc cross toolchains](http://www.kegel.com/crosstool/)
- [GCC Cross-Compiler](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler)
- [Cross Compiling With GCC](http://www.torriefamily.org/~torriem/cross/)

Answer (score 5):

yes, its possible and actually quite simple. Just `install gcc-multilib`.

Comment: Many distros don't package a 32bit gcc-multilib though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this should be possible. It's certainly possible on Mac OS X, where Apple's gcc toolchain supports x86, x86-64, ppc and ppc64, and you can compile for all 4 targets from a development machine that is 32 bit or 64 bit.

Answer (score -1):

You'd need to set up a cross compiler. And don't bother. Just run a 64-bit VM instead. You can run 64-bit VMs on a 32-bit host OS provided the CPU supports it (which it will, unless it's ancient).